# How to solve an iOS crash without app call stack?

Tags: ios, crash, segmentation-fault

Our app is crash online, not in debug mode.

We cannot reproduce the crash.

Here is the crash log which caught with [bugly](https://bugly.qq.com).

Anyone could help or some clue , Please!

```html
#43 Thread

SIGSEGV

SEGV_ACCERR

0 libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 16
1 CoreFoundation    ___CFPropertyListIsValidAux + 56
2 CoreFoundation    ___CFPropertyListIsDictPlistAux + 188
3 CoreFoundation    ___CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 24
4 CoreFoundation    _CFBasicHashApply + 132
5 CoreFoundation    CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 180
6 CoreFoundation    ___CFPropertyListIsValidAux + 388
7 CoreFoundation    CFPropertyListIsValid + 28
8 CFNetwork ___ZN12__CFURLCache23CreateAndStoreCacheNodeEP16__CFURLCacheNodePK20_CFCachedURLResponsePK10__CFStringPK13_CFURLRequestPKvbRb_block_invoke + 148
9 libdispatch.dylib __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
10 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_client_callout + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 592
12 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 432
13 libdispatch.dylib    __dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 600
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib  _pthread_wqthread + 312
```

[image: error thread]

[image: device info]

Comment: This is happening in a block being executed by CFNetwork. It looks like an internal function that is caching a URL (or the response to opening a URL?). It appears to be attempting to validate a Property List, but something is causing a crash during that action.

Comment: @user1118321thanks! but I still didn't find solution

Comment: So you crashed in `objc_msgSend`?  http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Comment: @matt Yes , still not have any clue :(

Comment: It looks as if a check for a valid property list fails. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) say: _The file itself is typically encoded using the Unicode UTF-8 encoding and the contents are structured using XML._ I would check that first.